# Proguard with APK and Android App Bundle (.aab)

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, android-proguard

I generated a signed APK file with Android Studio and I analyzed it to check if Proguard works correctly (and it works). I would like to upload to the Play Store a bundle file. If I click on Build, Generate Signed Bundle/APK and I select "Android App Bundle" instead of Apk, should Proguard work automatically or are there any rules that I have to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work automatically without changing anything. The same dex file is generated for APKs and for Android App Bundles.